# MySQL Between Statement and >= <= > < not working

Tags: mysql

i cant get my between statement to work, I can get `AND EffectiveDate >= '2015-06-01'` to work, as soon as i add another date condition it breaks. I have tried using `CAST('2015-06-01' AS DATE)` with no  success, i have also tried using `'2015-06-01 00:00:00'` variations of dates as well with no success.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Division, 
    EffectiveDate, 
    PM, 
    case Status 
        when 0 then 'Dead'
        when 1 then 'Active'
        when 2 then 'Job'
        when 3 then 'Pending'
        when 4 then 'Sales Lead'
        when 5 then 'Budget'
        when 6 then 'Change Order'
    end as Status, 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    ProjectType,
    sellPrice
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
    AND Status = 2 OR Status = 6
    AND EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30'
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
;
```

Comment: `CAST('2015-06-01' as date)` probably

Comment: If you want to use BETWEEN and such with dates, your fields need to be proper DATE fields.

Comment: tried that, sorry - edited my question :(

Comment: Are you sure that in your DDL you specified the EffectiveDate as DATE?

Comment: they are formatted as dates, not sure i understand what that looks like

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: all dates are returned

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with comparing date expressions. This is an issue with the *order of precedence* of `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with the query is that `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`: the condition on `EffectiveDate` does not apply to rows that have Division = 'TI'
and Status = 2.

You probably want to write

```
AND (Status = 2 OR Status = 6)
```

or, equivalently,

```
AND Status IN (2, 6)
```